# mysql query erro

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am using php and mysqli for my web project but every thing seems to be fine but it gives me boolean error at mysqli_num_rows();

[image]

Note: the first line I echo so I can see whether the values I entered are being passed or not and it works fine still on the next line it gives me error Boolean.

```
<?php
include("Database/database.php");
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['un'];
$upassword = $_SESSION['up'];
$varch = $_SESSION['ch'];
$sql = "SELECT `username`, `userpwd`, `userid` FROM `useraccount` WHERE username = '$uname' AND userpwd = '$upassword'";
echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if($rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
    if($varch == "on")
    {
        setcookie("name", $uname, time()+60*60*7);
        setcookie("password", $upassword, time()+60*60*7);
    }
    header('Location: useraccount.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_num\_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476056/warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

Comment: Where have you defined `$link` variable? Show code.

Comment: Your `mysqli_query($link, $sql)` is failing. Check `$link` and `$sql`.

Comment: `    <?php

     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");
     if(!$link)  
     {
         die("Failed to connect");
         echo '<script>window.alert("connection failed")</script>';
     }
     ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function "mysqli_query" returns the "mysqli_result object" when query run successfully.
Otherwise return "false".
In your case might be "false" is stored in $result might be query failed.
And "mysqli_num_rows" takes mysql_result object as parameter.Here when you

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

the "false" i.e boolean is found.Thats why the error is shown.

You need to execute the output query in mysql (phpmyadmin) first. Correct it.
and use in your code

Comment: I have solved it. you were right. there was error in query

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in manual

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You have to check if your query failed or returned empty result (contains FALSE value). You can do it in the same `if` where you have `$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result)`. It will look like that:

```
if($result !== FALSE && $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result))
```